# How to retrive a specific portion of a String in java

Tags: java

I have a requirement that i have to get a specific portion from a String i.e if i have java.lang.String i need to get the com field from the String i have done this

```
public class uu {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        String domain = "www.xyzw.com";
        String[] strArray = domain.split("\\.");
        for (String str : strArray) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

it is giving me three fields separately but i need the com only  ..
someone help me

Comment: why not use directly `strArray[2]`

Comment: `String com = strArray[strArray.length-1]`

Comment: `String s = domain.substring(domain.lastIndexOf(".")+1);`

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = domain.substring(domain.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
```

Consider inserting error checks for the case that the string does not contain `.`

Answer (score 1):

```
 String domain = "www.xyzw.com";
 String[] strArray = domain.split("\\.");
  System.out.println(strArray[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
String r = strArray[strArray.length - 1];
```

Or:

```
String r = domain.substring(domain.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work with domains you could use Google Guava `InternetDoMainNames` class. It is very simple

```
InternetDomainName.from("www.xyzw.com").publicSuffix();
```

How to use:
https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/InternetDomainNameExplained
http://koziolekweb.pl/2014/03/30/pomocna-guava-informacje-o-domenie/ (with example - translation to english is posible)